# Hide content beneath sticky element

Tags: javascript, css, sticky

I have a table with some sticky cells. I use a set of translucent color values in the overall design and I would like to use these on the table also but since the sticky cells are overlapping the translucent background colors is of course causing the content beneath to show if the table is scrolled.

[image]

I could of course define some solid background colors for the table so that the sticky cells would "hide" the content beneath but it would be nice if I could use the translucent color scheme so that the table also follows "layered" color scheme. So if the table would be placed on top of a lighter, or darker, background the colors of the overall table would be affected.

I was thinking of getting the effective color values in the table with JS but seams a bit to complex. I've also tried backdrop-filter with blur and it kind of looks nice but a bit of flicking is happening when scrolling.

Any ideas would be appreciated on how I could use translucent background colors in the table  but with a nice solution for "hiding" the content beneath the sticky cells.

```css
:root {
  --light-1: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06);
  --light-2: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  --light-3: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}

body {
  background-color: #111;
}

.tbl {
    max-width: 700px;
    color: #FFF;
    
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.tbl__tbl {
    width: 100%;
      border-spacing: 0;
}

.tbl__tbl th,
.tbl__tbl td {
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
}

.tbl__tbl th {
    background-color: var(--light-1);
}

.tbl__tbl tr:nth-of-type(odd) td {
    background-color: var(--light-3);
}

.tbl__tbl tr:nth-of-type(even) td {
    background-color: var(--light-2);
}

.tbl__tbl .tbl__act {
    width: 1%;
    position: sticky;
    right: 0;
    padding-top: 0.75rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.75rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="tbl">
            <table class="tbl__tbl">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th class="tbl__act"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Value</td>
                            <td>Value</td>
                            <td>Value</td>
                            <td>Value</td>
                            <td>Value</td>
                            <td>Value</td>
                            <td>Value</td>
                            <td>Value</td>
                            <td>Value</td>
                            <td class="tbl__act">sticky</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Value</td>
                            <td>Value</td>
                            <td>Value</td>
                            <td>Value</td>
                            <td>Value</td>
                            <td>Value</td>
                            <td>Value</td>
                            <td>Value</td>
                            <td>Value</td>
                            <td class="tbl__act">sticky</td>
                        </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```